# Embed a page completely using iframe, no border, no whitespace where the border once was

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have the following code

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://anothersite.com" style="width:100%; height:100%;  overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;"   marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" seamless="seamless" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

that has an iframe that I want to display another site in, just like it was a page on the website. However there is some white space that still exists when the border is removed and scrolling bar is still there but it's only still. I want it invisible but still scroll-able, and the border space gone. Please any help would be appreciated. I haven't found a straight forward answer that has worked for me on the browser I am using (Chrome). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page always has a default margin/padding, and that differs between browsers and the mode that the browser uses.

Add a doctype so that the page isn't rendered in quirks mode (as that makes it less predictable). Add a style sheet that removes the margin and padding from the body element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page name</title>
<style>
html { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://anothersite.com" style="width:100%; height:100%;  overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;"   marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" seamless="seamless" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. However now there is a problem with the height. For whatever reason it's about 200px. Also the scroll bar is on the side. Would you happen to know how to fix these problems?

Comment: @user1917363: Try to set the height of the `html` and `body` elements, and set `overflow:hidden` to get rid of the scrollbar. See the code above.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me come to a complete solutions which works in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Opera. My final code for anyone's future use it <!DOCTYPE html style="height:100%">
<style>
html, body{overflow: hidden;} 
</style>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
<iframe src="YOUR SITE TO LINK TO" style="width:100%; height:100%; "   scrollbar="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" seamless="seamless" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You should really have the `html` tag and the `head` tag. Even if what you have works in current browsers, it's a bad tag soup which might stop working if a future version of a browser decides to interpret the invalid code in a different way.

Comment: Thank you. have made note of that and will do